# Render value for no matches found in react-autocomplete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-autocomplete

I am using the [react-autocomplete](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-autocomplete) npm package to build the autocomplete functionality in my Reactjs app. So far I have been able to render dropdown items that match the user's input, as you see in the documentation of this package. However, I would like to generate a default text in the dropdown as `No results found` whenever user's input do not match any of the dropdown items. And to be honest I am really struggling with it.

I tried adding custom function to the `shouldItemRender` to change the state and dropdown items accordingly but it does not help either. Here is the snippet of my code -

```
const suggestions=  [{id: 100 , text:  "Aluminium extracts" }, {id: 101 , text:  "Copper extracts" }] 

<Autocomplete
    getItemValue={(item) => item.text}
    items={ suggestions }
    renderItem={(item, isHighlighted) => {
            return <div> {item.text} </div>)
        }
    }
    shouldItemRender={(item, value) => item.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) > -1}
    // shouldItemRender={(item, value) => handleRender(item, value) }
    value={value}
    onChange={(e, newValue) => { setValue(e.target.value) }}
    onSelect={(v) => handleInput(v)}
    inputProps={{ placeholder: "start typing"}}
/>
```

I will appreciate your help if you can help me accomplish this. Thank you.

Comment: Does this help? [Custom Menu Example](https://github.com/reactjs/react-autocomplete/blob/master/examples/custom-menu/app.js#L52,L62)

Comment: I tried conditional rendering of `items` using `renderMenu` as shown in the example above but it does not help, it breaks everything :(

Comment: Could you please create a minimal reproducible stackblitz link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `renderMenu` to check whether a match found or not. If there is no match found then show the **No match found**, if match found then return the items and `renderItem` will render the items list.

```
<ReactAutocomplete
  items={[
    { id: "foo", label: "foo" },
    { id: "bar", label: "bar" },
    { id: "baz", label: "baz" },
  ]}
  shouldItemRender={(item, value) =>
    item.label.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) > -1
  }
  getItemValue={(item) => item.label}
  renderItem={(item, highlighted) => (
    <div
      key={item.id}
      style={{ backgroundColor: highlighted ? "#eee" : "transparent" }}
    >
      {item.label}
    </div>
  )}
  renderMenu={(items, value) => (
    <div>{items.length === 0 ? `No matches for ${value}` : items}</div>
  )}
  value={this.state.value}
  onChange={(e) => this.setState({ value: e.target.value })}
  onSelect={(value) => this.setState({ value })}
/>
```

Check this link for better understanding.
https://github.com/reactjs/react-autocomplete/blob/master/examples/custom-menu/app.js

Answer (score 0):

The best way to provide message for the case where there are no options is to use `renderMenu` prop to override the result of dropdown content when no items found to matching search criteria.

```
import { useState } from "react";

const suggestions = [
  { id: 100, text: "Aluminium extracts" },
  { id: 101, text: "Copper extracts" }
];

export default function App() {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
  const items = suggestions.filter((item) =>
    item.text.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
  );
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Autocomplete
        getItemValue={(item) => item.text}
        renderMenu={(items) =>
          items.length > 0 ? <div children={items} /> : <div>No results found</div>
        }
        items={items}
        renderItem={(item, isHighlighted) => {
          return <div> {item.text} </div>;
        }}
        value={searchTerm}
        onChange={(e, newValue) => {
          setSearchTerm(e.target.value);
        }}
        onSelect={(text) => setSearchTerm(text)}
        inputProps={{ placeholder: "start typing" }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make it simple & Use `renderMenu` instead of `renderItem` for Component rendering.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this?

```
items={ suggestions.lenght ? suggestions : [{id: -1, text: "No results found" }] }
isItemSelectable=(item)=>item.id !== -1
```

Comment: It does not unfortunately work.